# htaccess rules for Linux to Windows

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have following .htaccess rules which are basically defined for Linux environment, but i want to use them on my Xampp localhost on windows. Cant figure out on how to change them so it can work with windows too, or it should be so that local environment works and live works too.

```
# Ensure www is in front of domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

if use the same rules i get **object not Found 404**, dont know how to make it work on my xampp local.

**EDIT Access Logs**

```
::1 - - [24/Jul/2018:19:50:57 +0500] "GET /rds-core/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1054 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
::1 - - [24/Jul/2018:20:22:36 +0500] "GET /rds-core/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1054 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
```

Comment: None of these rules are very filesystem-specific. So what's the input urls, vhost settings, access.log, and **RewriteLog** (enable it!) details?

Comment: @mario: well input URL be like, `localhost/rds-core` , havent created any Vhost history. Dont know about rest.

Comment: Well, long story short: there's no point in using these rules, unless your XAMPP webserver has been configured with identical ssl vhosts. Without the Rewrite/Access/ErrorLogs this is basically a "guess my problem" question.

Comment: ok, let me see if i can check logs

Comment: @mario: please check, logs pasted.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located on XAMPP serup? Is .htaccess enabled?

Comment: @anubhava, its located like this `root/manage/.htaccess`

Comment: ok move your .htaccess inside `/rds-core/` and retest